# How to get dimensions of an uploaded Video in Azure Media Services (PHP SDK/Django project)

Tags: php, django, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I have a Django app that contains a Video-on-Demand feature. It's powered by Azure Media Services (AMS). When a user uploads a video, I first save the video in an Azure storage blob, and then I use a PHP script (which utilizes the AMS php sdk) to encode the said video and prep a streaming URL (hosted on AMS).

My problem is this: how do I get the **dimensions** of the video? I need to know the height and width so that I can encode the video to lower res formats on AMS. I can't get the dimensions from python since I'm not uploading the video file onto a local server first (where my web server is running). What are my options? Please advise.

Comment: I am a little confused, as that don't your user use your application to upload video? Why you can't get the dimensions during the uploading progress? And additionally, could you tell the work flow of your PHP script?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT: The PHP script is simply taken from this example: http://southworks.com/blog/2015/12/09/new-microsoft-azure-media-services-sdk-for-php-release-available-with-new-features-and-samples/ I guess one option is getting the dimensions via JS at the time of uploading. That's something I haven't explored yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using AMS SDK for PHP to create AMS task, and which requires the video asset file. You can leverage the PHP module http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ to get the info of video asset during the PHP process with a ease.

You can download the PHP module http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ and extract to your php application's folder, and you can use the following code snippet to get the dimensions of video asset:

```
require_once('./getid3/getid3.php');
$filename="<video_path>"; 
$getID3 = new getID3;
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($filename);
var_dump($ThisFileInfo['asf']['video_media']);
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

## update using remotefile on Azure Storage

Here is a code sample, leveraging which, you can use the SAS url of blobs on Azure Storage. It will download the file to server folder, and detect the info, and then delete the template file.

```
$remotefilename = '<SAS Url>';
if ($fp_remote = fopen($remotefilename, 'rb')) {
    $localtempfilename = tempnam('/tmp', 'getID3');
    if ($fp_local = fopen($localtempfilename, 'wb')) {
        while ($buffer = fread($fp_remote, 8192)) {
            fwrite($fp_local, $buffer);
        }
        fclose($fp_local);
        // Initialize getID3 engine
        $getID3 = new getID3;
        $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($localtempfilename);
        // Delete temporary file
        unlink($localtempfilename);
    }
    fclose($fp_remote);
    var_dump($ThisFileInfo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Gary. We'll test it out.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the file on my server. I upload it to an Azure blob, from where I encode it for the Azure Media Server. This I can't pass the filename like so `$getID3->analyze($filename);`. Do I have any alternative here?

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'll try this. As an aside, would you suggest this to be the most efficient way to upload/encode videos on AMS? Another option is I first upload the file onto my server, process it there, and then upload it to Azure Blob/AMS (and delete it from my server). What do you suggest is the most efficient work flow? I'm trying to implement a Video On Demand feature.

Comment: What strange to me is that, why you don't use your second option to build your application. Whatever for your current structure, you can leverage Blob Storage, Table Storage and Queue Storage. You use Blob Storage to store your assets, use Table Storage to store the origin asset url, AMS asset url, and some other info of your asset.

Comment: And use Queue storage to send messages. You can use your Django application to handle upload files, then send a message to Queue. And you can build up a work job with your PHP application, with which you can get the message from Queue, and encode the told asset via AMS SDK, then update in the Table Storage.

Comment: Fair enough. And in this set up, will my first step be uploading the file to my own server first (so that I can get the dimensions of the video - which I'll save in Table storage later like you said)?

Comment: Not must Table storage, I mean, you always need a database to store the info of your video assets, right? And if you have trouble in get dimensions of the video in your Django application, I think you can do the least modification on your current structure.